# Kick and ban command isnt working for me anymore, even though I havent changed it

Tags: visual-studio-code, command, discord.js

I successfully make a kick and ban a day or two ago and today I was testing it again and it suddenly wasn't working and I can't figure out why. I don't believe that I had changed anything inside the command besides the set color.

And now the `kick @user` doesn't delete after sent either. However, the embed sends telling me that the person had been kicked. I'm using discord.js and Visual Studio code. I'm also new to coding and making bots.

I've tried changing the message.guild.member(kUser).kick(kReason) and changing the order of things.

```
// A command to ban certain people aand will then send me a dm
    case 'ban':
            if(message.member.roles.find("name", "Owner")){

                let bUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
                if (!bUser) return message.channel.send("Who is being banned?");
                let bReason = args.join("Banned  ").slice(3);
              message.delete();
                let banEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                  .setDescription("Ban Management")
                  .setColor(0xf44242)
                  .addField("Banned User", `${bUser.user.tag} with ID ${bUser.id}`)
                  .addField("Banned By", `<@${message.author.id}> with ID ${message.author.id}`)
                  .addField("Banned In", message.channel.name)
                  .addField("Time", message.createdAt)
                  .addField("Reason", bReason);


                // sends me a dm
                  bot.users.get("485655477812723712").send(banEmbed);  // 485655477812723712 is second sofiras id
                  message.guild.member(bUser).ban(bReason)           

                }else{
                    message.channel.sendMessage('You have not been granted this ability');
                }


              break;

    // command to kick certain people and then send me a dm 
    case 'kick':
            if(message.member.roles.find("name", "Owner")){
                let kUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
                if (!kUser) return message.channel.send("Who is being kicked?");
                let kReason = args.join("Kicked ").slice(4);

                let kickEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                  .setDescription("Ban Management")
                  .setColor(0xf44242)
                  .addField("Kicked User", `${kUser.user.tag} with ID ${kUser.id}`)
                  .addField("kicked By", `<@${message.author.id}> with ID ${message.author.id}`)
                  .addField("Kicked In", message.channel.name)
                  .addField("Time", message.createdAt)
                  .addField("Reason", kReason);

                  // sends me a dm
                  bot.users.get("485655477812723712").send(kickEmbed); // 485655477812723712 is second sofiras id
                  message.guild.member(kUser).kick(kReason)

                }else{
                    message.channel.sendMessage('You have not been granted this ability')

            }

              break;
```

I expected that when I sent the command that the person would be kicked or banned, delete that command/message, and then send me to embed, however, it just sends the embed. Doesn't delete the command/message and doesn't kick or ban the member.

Comment: Are any errors thrown?

Answer (score 1):

- I don't see you deleting the command message anywhere in your code.
  [`message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)
- When you're banning or kicking the member, you're not using the `options` parameter correctly.
  [`bUser.ban({ reason: bReason })`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) / [`kUser.kick({ reason: kReason })`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick)
- There's a few other improvements I've made in the code below, like catching rejected promises, removing redundant code, performing more checks before banning, passing a function into [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find), and removing the deprecated [`Channel.sendMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendMessage) call. I've only done this to one of the commands since you can implement these improvements in both.

```js
// Async context needed in order to use the keyword 'await'

case 'ban':
  try {
    if (!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Owner')) return await message.channel.send(':x: Insufficient permission.');

    const banning = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);

    if (!banning) return await message.channel.send(':x: No user provided.');
    if (banning.id === bot.user.id) return await message.channel.send(':x: Think you\'re smart?');
    if (!banning.bannable || banning.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Owner')) return await message.channel.send(':x: Insufficient permission.');

    const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') || '*None*'; // Assuming args[1] is the reason

    await message.delete();

    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0xf44242)
      .setTitle('**Ban Management**')
      .setDescription('A user has been banned.')
      .addField('User', `${banning.user} (${banning.user.tag})`)
      .addField('Moderator', `${message.author} (${message.author.tag})`)
      .addField('Location', `${message.channel} (${message.channel.name})`)
      .addField('Reason', `${reason}`)
      .setTimestamp();

    const me = bot.users.get('485655477812723712');
    await me.send(embed);

    await banning.ban({ reason: reason });
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work no matter what I did, though I did figure out what had changed. Not why the code wouldn't work. I had forgotten that I had changed servers I was on and so when I went back to the old one it worked perfectly, though  few problems were occurring. So I'm just really confused now. But oh well. I don't know why it was only the kick and ban command that wasn't working in the new server or why I "if (msg.author.bot) return;" started showing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bot' of undefined discord.js" when it hadn't before.

Comment: Sounds like `msg` isn't a message. Check your message event parameters.

Comment: this is the code, and it didnt used to give me problems. bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
    let msg = "message"
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
    bot.users.get("485655477812723712").send(member + "has joined your server!") 
    .catch(console.error);
})

Comment: There is no `message` in a `guildMemberAdd` event. Since you're declaring a variable `msg` as a string, there's no `author` property. You could use `member.user.bot` instead of `msg.author.bot`.

Comment: Oh opps. Wrong one :p I just didnt want to be sent 2 dms when someone left. as if someone is kicked or banned I get a dm, and then when someone leaves I get sent a dm. So I would get two. I just wanted to avoid that is all, i guess. `// sends me a dm that someone left
bot.on("guildMemberRemove", member => {
    if (member.user.bot) return;
    bot.users.get("485655477812723712").send(member + 'has left the server') 
})`